# Set ant property by invoking a shell script?

Tags: ant, properties

Is there any way to set an ant property by capturing the output of a shellscript? (or another ant task)

Something like this:

```
<property name="foo">
    <value>
        <exec executable="bar" />
    </value>
</property>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that exec task has an outputproperty-property, like so:

```
<exec executable="bar" outputproperty="foo" />
```

Answer (score 8):

From the [ANT exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

1. Set the `output` attribute : *Name of a file to which to write the output.*
2. As Marble has suggested - set the `outputproperty`

When I tested they came out to be mutually exclusive. So set only 1 of them at a time.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @Nim's answer:

The  tag can appear as an immediate child of the . It doesn't have to be inside a . This gives it global scope, like a  tag.

Also, if you need a complex command, you can use `arg` tags.

For example, if you want to add the Git branch name to a jar manifest, you do something like this:

```
 <project>

    <property name="user" value="fred"/>

    <!-- git.branch gets set globally -->
    <exec executable="/usr/bin/git" outputproperty="git.branch">
      <arg value="rev-parse"/>
      <arg value="--abbrev-ref"/>
      <arg value="HEAD"/>
    </exec>

    <target name="make-jar">
      <jar jarfile="project.jar">
        <manifest>
          <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user}"/>
          <attribute name="Git-Branch" value="${git.branch}"/>
        </manifest>
        <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class"/>
      </jar>
    </target>
  </project>
```

Comment: how can I use the value of *git.branch* outsides the <exec...> ...</exec> block?

Comment: @Heinz As it says in the answer; use it in a _value_ parameter. Where do you want to use it?

Comment: I don't get it either. The property disappears once the exec block finishes. How can it be made into a variable?

Comment: @tobidelbruck I expanded the answer a bit. The basic idea is that an exec block can be outside a target and then its output is available globally.

Comment: My bad, I had a typo, called the property `git.tag` and then used `git-tag` later (dash not dot). thanks for getting me to look at it again!