# Ant build -- optionally override location of java executable

Tags: java, ant

I have several java projects on the same machine which really need to be built with different java compilers, one with java 1.6 and one with java 1.7. (No, it's not sufficient to build them with the higher version of java and specify source and target for the project that requires the lower version-- the differences between them produce test failures).

My colleagues do not have this problem -- they have only one project that requires 1.6. I would like to put in some configuration that enables me to override the java compiler without requiring them to add environment variables. I'm imagining something like this:

```
<javac executable='${java.executable.path}' srcdir='${src.dir}' destdir='${dest.dir.classes}' source='1.6' target='1.6' fork='true'  />
```

where `${java.executable.path}` is defined earlier in the file as:

```
<condition property="java.executable.path" value="${env.PROJ_JAVA_HOME}" else="${DEFAULT_JAVAC}">
    <isset property="env.PROJ_JAVA_HOME" />
</condition>
```

except... there is no `${DEFAULT_JAVAC}` that I can find. Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing? Or is ant just not built for things like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could default to whatever javac is on the path.

its possible to [set an ant property by executing a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364467/set-ant-property-by-invoking-a-shell-script), so you'll need to execute something like `which javac`

Comment: Good idea! I hadn't thought of that. You probably meant to link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364467/set-ant-property-by-invoking-a-shell-script) instead though.

Comment: @Denise - too many open tabs :-) anyway, i dont know if you care but that would make your build non-portable (tied to a specific OS), unless you add yet another layer to detect the OS and come up with the appropriate shell command ... personally i would have forced users of the build to define JAVAC_HOME and failed the build if it wasnt defined.

Comment: Strange as it may seem, I'm hoping we can standardize to one java version before we have to deal with people developing on different OSes. (We're all on the same one now).